# Product View Page Header and Footer part is not Showing In Magento 2

Tags: magento2, frontend, product-view, header, footer

On the website, home page ***header and footer*** showing but product page not showing header and footer part. How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: did you run deploy command. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please review this file in your custom theme, there may be some issues..

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

Or try to rename this from `list.phtml` to `list1.phtml` and run below commands once

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Let me know if it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please press **CTRL + U** in your keyboard and check **view source** of that page. There may be some error. That's why you're not getting header and footer there.

Hope this will help you to debug more!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the path:

```
app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

**or**

```
app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml
```

find code and remove after flush command :

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true" />
<referenceContainer name="footer" remove="true" />
```

Comment: is their any other solution? because this two <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true" />
<referenceContainer name="footer" remove="true" /> is not found in my files

Comment: ok, can you check in the parent theme?